# How to INSERT INTO in ONE TABLE from MULTIPLE TABLES?

Tags: sql, sql-insert, libreoffice-base

I will make you an example with GRADES MINUTES and SECONDS on three different tables.

```
T_GRADES
ID_GRADE
- Primary Key
- Autoincrement
GRADE
- Numeric (all numbers from 0 to 359)

T_MINUTES
ID_MINUTE
- Primary Key
- Autoincrement
MINUTE
- Numeric (all numbers from 0 to 59)

T_SECONDS
ID_SECOND
- Primary Key
- Autoincrement
SECOND
- Numeric (all numbers from 0 to 59)
```

With this query I can see all data from all three tables.

```
SELECT "T_GRADES"."GRADE", "T_MINUTES"."MINUTE", "T_SECONDS"."SECOND"
FROM "T_GRADES" "T_GRADES", "T_MINUTES" "T_MINUTES", "T_SECONDS" "T_SECONDS"
ORDER BY "GRADO", "PRIMO", "SECONDO"
```

Now, how can I select INSERT INTO a 4th TABLE called T_GMS with these fields like a CROSS JOIN between all three tables?

```
T_GMS
ID_GMS
- Primary Key
- Autoincrement
GRADE
- Numeric (all numbers from 0 to 359)
PRIME
- Numeric (all numbers from 0 to 59)
SECOND
- Numeric (all numbers from 0 to 59)
```

Thank you so much in advance for your answers.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/

Answer (score 0):

To create a new table from the results of a query you can use INTO [Table] command before FROM.
e.g

```
SELECT * INTO [Tbl_NewTable] FROM [tbl_User],[tbl_Role]
```

If your table already exists, you have to use INSERT INTO [Table] command before SELECT

```
INSERT INTO [Tbl_NewTable] SELECT * FROM [tbl_User],[tbl_Role]
```

make sure your selected columns in query results must be same as the NewTable columns

Comment: Owais, I must select "three fields" each from "three" different tables and not from just "one" table,

Comment: To create a new table from a SELECT statement you need to use `create table .. as select ..`in "SQL" - you wrote a T-SQL answer, but the `sql` tag refers to standard SQL, not a specific DBMS product

Comment: @LucaDELPARTITA yes, you can select columns from different table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your 4th table exists, you can simply do

```
INSERT INTO T_GMS ("GRADE", "PRIME", "SECOND")
SELECT "GRADE", "MINUTE", "SECOND"
FROM "T_GRADES", "T_MINUTES", "T_SECONDS"
ORDER BY "GRADE", "MINUTE", "SECOND"
```

The primary key will be generated automatically, and you specify which values go into which columns by the order of the columns listed in the brackets after T_GMS.

I cut out all the aliases for simplicity (I do not think you need them).  Also your SQL seemed a little confused on naming, so please check.